How do I debug iOS Background Task in MAUI (Xamarin iOS)?
My question is similar to Xamarin iOS - How to debug a background service but there is no answer there. I know there is this guide from Apple but I am not really sure how to do that from MAUI:

In the debugger, execute the line shown below, substituting the identifier of the desired task for TASK_IDENTIFIER.

e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"TASK_IDENTIFIER"]

My question is, how do I call the above code in .NET MAUI?
I think I will need to make a binding since there doesn't seem to be any binding in MAUI's BGTaskScheduler for _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier. How do I do that?

You will need to use the Xcode debugger

@Paulw11 unfortunately I do not know how to get the code into XCode. I assume I need to use Attach to Process but since it wasn't started by XCode I don't know how to attach it as well...

As long as you know the bundle Id for your app you can tell the Xcode debugger to look for the process and attach to it when it launches.
